# Do I need async for Razor Page OnGet ActionResult if View Components only make an async call

Tags: c#, async-await, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm upgrading my Web App from .Net Framework 4.6 to Asp.Net Core 2.2 Razor Pages and in the process I moved a bunch of code from **Partial Views** to **View Components**.  Before my `ActionResult` method looked like this...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnGetAsync(int book, int chapter)
```

It did a lot of work to populate all the partial views before I returned returned the page.  Part of this consisted of reading from a database and I accomplished this with an `await` call like this...

```
Scriptures = await db.ByBookAndChapterAsync(book, chapter);
```

That code got moved to a View Component `InvokeAsync` method like...

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int book, int chapter)
```

Not having the `await` call to the database in my `ActionResult` the compiler complains

> async method lacks await operators

so I changed it so that it it looks like...

```
public ActionResult OnGet(int book, int chapter)
```

It works, but is **it the best approach?** that's my question

Also, FWIW, here is how I call my **View Component** from inside the **Razor Page**, it looks like...

```
    <vc:scriptures book=@Model.BookId chapter=@Model.Chapter></vc:scriptures>
```

I converted my `ActionResult` to not be `async`, and it works, but is that correct? Am I mixing sync with async inappropriately?

Thanks

Comment: The View is not generated by the Controller, so you are just fine following the compiler's advice

Comment: Technically it's not a controller because I'm using Razor Pages which use events (e.g. OnGet or OnGetAsync), but anyway I'm glad to get confirmation for my approach.  I have read that a description of async is like "turtles all the way down" and I didn't want to miss a turtle.  Thanks